# Multi touch code doesnt work

Tags: java, android

So I am wroking on game game for android and it requires the use of multi touch. I have read some tutorials about multi touch and tryed to use it in my game.
This is my code:

```
    public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent e) {
    int pointerCount = e.getPointerCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < pointerCount; i++) {
        int x = (int) e.getX(i);
        int y = (int) e.getY(i);
        int action = e.getActionMasked();

        for (int j = 0; j < object.size(); j++) {
            tempObject = object.get(j);
            if (tempObject.getId() == ObjectId.Player) {

                switch (action) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (moveLeft.contains(x, y)) {
                        tempObject.setMovingLeft(false);

                    }
                    if (moveRight.contains(x, y)) {
                        tempObject.setMovingRight(false);

                    }

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    if (moveLeft.contains(x, y)) {
                        tempObject.setMovingLeft(false);

                    }
                    if (moveRight.contains(x, y)) {
                        tempObject.setMovingRight(false);

                    }

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (jump.contains(x, y)) {
                        if (tempObject.getVelY() == 0 && tempObject.isJumping() == false) {
                            tempObject.setVelY((float) -11.5);
                            tempObject.setJumping(true);
                        }
                    }
                    if (restart.contains(x, y)) {
                        restart();

                    }

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    if (jump.contains(x, y)) {
                        if (tempObject.getVelY() == 0 && tempObject.isJumping() == false) {
                            tempObject.setVelY((float) -11.5);
                            tempObject.setJumping(true);
                        }
                    }
                    if (restart.contains(x, y)) {
                        restart();

                    }

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    if (moveLeft.contains(x, y)) {
                        tempObject.setMovingLeft(true);
                        tempObject.setMovingRight(false);

                    }
                    if (moveLeftExit.contains(x, y) && !moveLeft.contains(x, y)) {
                        tempObject.setMovingLeft(false);

                    }
                    if (moveRight.contains(x, y)) {
                        tempObject.setMovingRight(true);
                        tempObject.setMovingLeft(false);

                    }
                    if (moveRightExit.contains(x, y) && !moveRight.contains(x, y)) {
                        tempObject.setMovingRight(false);

                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

EDIT:
I had a mistake mixing the for loops varibels, now it doesnt crash but the touch doesnt work.

EDIT2:
I have now noticed that the multi touch works, but it gets trigered when I press in a different place than the Rectangles where it should..

EDIT3:
Now the good part is that the multi touch work,as in I can press two buttons and they both react.
The bad part is that they react when I touch a different and smaller place.
I hope you can understand from this picture:

[image]

## black - Where it is suppose to trigger the touch event

## yellow- Where the touch event is triggered.

Thanks ! Smiley

Comment: Elaborating more on the functionality you want: so you have some rectangles that, when touched (ACTION_DOWN), should do something? So the problem is only for ACTION_DOWN or for which case?

Comment: @fersarr the actions work fine ,please see edit3 for explanation.

Comment: (0,0) is located in the upper left. as is common in graphics.

Comment: So the problem could be with your coordinates for jump and restart buttons? May be you can paste the part of code in which you set those coords and keep in mind what @corn3lius said

Comment: also you need to check the density-independant pixel size as it will scale images based on devices capacity. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 4):

This looks weird:

```
for (int j = 0; i < object.size(); j++) {
```

**mixing up i and j** ? This might be causing the index out of bounds error

Answer (score 0):

The Exceptionn was caused by the array list.in which you are trying to access the index which is out of range.

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 83, size is 83